Failed to start gdm.service during booting
All this started when, in my dual boot laptop with intel graphics card having a functional Ubuntu 24.10 and a corrupted Windows 10, I booted into my corrupted Windows which obviously was not successful, but when I returned to boot in my Ubuntu, it just said...
Failed to start snap.service Failed to start gdm.service
Note that I have tried to do all the steps like --fix-missing install -reinstall and whatnot, everything that ChatGPT told me to do. While doing install --reinstall, it showed unable to fetch then an archive repository. I left it untouched then...
Now when I go to tty1 or tty2, I first mount in read-write, then I dpkg-reconfigure gdm3, then I do systemctl restart gdm3, then my boot completes. I am frustrated by this, still after doing all this I have to manually enable snapd to perform all functions.
This is what is showing while booting.

